# Visual Studio, GitHub/NuGet source and Symbol server

Tags: visual-studio

I use Visual Studio for everyday work and I would like to have similar functions to Rider/ReSharper. Specifically, I was wondering if it was possible to make sure that when I press F12 on a .NET object I see the source code. For libraries downloaded from NuGet it works but not for .NET objects. Also I would like to have the real-time IL code generated by Roslyn.
Thanks everyone for your replies.

Comment: You want these features _without_ having ReSharper installed?

Comment: Yes if possible

Comment: I read that with the new version of VS 2022 you can view the decompiled source with ILSpy.